eqparbox plugin, but without unnecessary tag
I need to define width of \parbox based on content size of that box.
eqparbox doing exactly that (unnecessary things removed):
\newcommand{\proove}[2]{\fbox {\eqparbox{#1}{#2}}}


But it require unecessary unique tag, and i required to provide it every time i use my custom command. Is there any other way to define \parbox width and heigh based on content? (multiline)

it is quite unclear how you want to set the size and what content your parbox can have. Make a small but complete example that demonstrates what you want to achieve.

@UlrikeFischer Updated

an "example" means code. Show how you would do that with eqparbox.

@UlrikeFischer nah, its literraly \fbox{\eqparbox{uniqid}{content}}... Updated anyway

You don't need eqparbox for this, since you don't reference the box width or reuse it elsewhere. Instead, just set the contents as-is inside an \fbox, or provide a box if it requires it; that is, use a \makebox, \mbox, \parbox, minipage or varwidth (last shown below).

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools,varwidth,lipsum}
\newcommand*{\defeq}[1]{\stackrel{\mathclap{\text{#1}}}{=}}
\newcommand*{\defimp}[1]{\stackrel{\mathclap{\text{#1}}}{\implies}}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}% Remove \parindent (just for this example}

\begin{document} 

\fbox{$\begin{aligned}
  a \times b &\defeq{A1} a \times (0 + b) \defeq{A9} a \times 0 + a \times b \\
  a \times b &= a \times 0 + a \times b \defimp{C3} 0 \times a  = (a \times b) - (a \times b) \\
  0 \times a &= (a \times b) - (a \times b) \defeq{C4} (a \times b) + (-(a \times b)) \defeq{A2} 0
\end{aligned}$}

\fbox{box size depends on the content}

\fbox{\begin{varwidth}{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}
\lipsum[1]
\end{varwidth}}

\fbox{\begin{varwidth}{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}
\begin{itemize}
  \item \strut First item
  \begin{itemize}
    \item Nested first item
    \item Nested second item
    \item Nested third item
    \item Nested last item
  \end{itemize}
  \item Second item
  \item Third item
  \item Last item
\end{itemize}
\end{varwidth}}

\end{document}

